# UnsatisfiedDependencyException for Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2 application using Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to rewrite the `DataConfiguration.java` implementation of a JHipster application with Kotlin.  The method I'm having problems with is:

```
@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase(@Qualifier("taskExecutor") TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
        DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {

    // Use liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase if you don't want Liquibase to start asynchronously
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new AsyncSpringLiquibase(taskExecutor, env);
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
    liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
    liquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema());
    liquibase.setDropFirst(liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst());
    if (env.acceptsProfiles(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_NO_LIQUIBASE)) {
        liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
    } else {
        liquibase.setShouldRun(liquibaseProperties.isEnabled());
        log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
    }
    return liquibase;
}
```

which I've rewritten as:

```
@Bean
fun liquibase(@Qualifier("taskExecutor") taskExecutor: TaskExecutor,
              dataSource: DataSource, liquibaseProperties: LiquibaseProperties): SpringLiquibase {

    // Use liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase if you don't want Liquibase to start asynchronously
    val liquibase = AsyncSpringLiquibase(taskExecutor, env)
    liquibase.dataSource = dataSource
    liquibase.changeLog = "classpath:config/liquibase/master.yml"
    liquibase.contexts = liquibaseProperties.contexts
    liquibase.defaultSchema = liquibaseProperties.defaultSchema
    liquibase.isDropFirst = liquibaseProperties.isDropFirst
    if (env.acceptsProfiles(SPRING_PROFILE_NO_LIQUIBASE)) {
        liquibase.setShouldRun(false)
    } else {
        liquibase.setShouldRun(liquibaseProperties.isEnabled)
        log.debug("Configuring Liquibase")
    }
    return liquibase
}
```

When I run the Spring Boot application I get the following exception `Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/sample/myapplication/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'liquibase' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`.

Any ideas what I might be missing?  I'm using Gradle to run the application, and I'm basing my configuration on a unmodified JHipster microservice application.

Let me know if there are any other code snippets I need to provide for my question to make sense.

Comment: Does the java code work?

Comment: @guenhter Yes, the Java code works fine.  It gets generated by the JHipster Yeoman generator.

Comment: Any solution to this?